# How do I parse a .pls file using PHP? Having trouble with parse_ini_file

Tags: php, parsing

I have this file:

```
[playlist]
numberofentries=4
File1=http://108.61.73.119:8128
Title1=(#1 - 266/1000) 181.FM - POWER 181 -=[: The Hitz Channel :]=- www.181.fm
Length1=-1
File2=http://108.61.73.118:8128
Title2=(#2 - 318/1000) 181.FM - POWER 181 -=[: The Hitz Channel :]=- www.181.fm
Length2=-1
File3=http://108.61.73.117:8128
Title3=(#3 - 401/1000) 181.FM - POWER 181 -=[: The Hitz Channel :]=- www.181.fm
Length3=-1
File4=http://198.27.79.224:9770
Title4=(#4 - 27/50) 181.FM - POWER 181 -=[: The Hitz Channel :]=- www.181.fm
Length4=-1
Version=2
```

I'd like to parse it and get only file and title. Problem is parse_ini_file gives me bogus error. I tried normal way, like I would parse text file but it is becoming complicated with too much trimming.

Any thoughts?

php:

```
$streams = parse_ini_file("tunein-station.pls", true);
print_r($streams);
```

Error:

```
PHP Warning:  parse error in tunein-station.pls on line 4\n
```

Comment: What is your "bogus error"? Are we supposed to guess? What is your code? Are we supposed to guess?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit error is cannot parse. I believe it is because Title has no double quotes around them.

Comment: Thanks for adding these crucial details into your question. Yes, non-alphanumeric values should be surrounded in double quotes. Perhaps you can do some pre-processing before passing to `parse_ini_file`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the `INI_SCANNER_RAW` scanner, something like this:

```
parse_ini_file('playlist.ini', true, INI_SCANNER_RAW);
```

This should handle strings with spaces and `[]`s without `"` around them better. See scanner modes at the [`parse_ini_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php)'s manual.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can perform some preprocessing on the input file to make it a valid INI file:

```
<?php
// 1. Read your INI file into a string (here we hardcode it for the demo)
$str = <<<EOF
[playlist]
numberofentries=4
File1=http://108.61.73.119:8128
Title1=(#1 - 266/1000) 181.FM - POWER 181 -=[: The Hitz Channel :]=- www.181.fm
Length1=-1
File2=http://108.61.73.118:8128
Title2=(#2 - 318/1000) 181.FM - POWER 181 -=[: The Hitz Channel :]=- www.181.fm
Length2=-1
File3=http://108.61.73.117:8128
Title3=(#3 - 401/1000) 181.FM - POWER 181 -=[: The Hitz Channel :]=- www.181.fm
Length3=-1
File4=http://198.27.79.224:9770
Title4=(#4 - 27/50) 181.FM - POWER 181 -=[: The Hitz Channel :]=- www.181.fm
Length4=-1
Version=2
EOF;

// 2. Add quotes around the "title" values
$str = preg_replace('/^(Title\d+)=(.*)$/m', '\1="\2"', $str);

// 3. Now parse as INI
$array = parse_ini_string($str);

// 4. Here are your results:
print_r($array);
?>
```

### [Live demo](http://ideone.com/Q2tBZp)

Output:

```
Array
(
    [numberofentries] => 4
    [File1] => http://108.61.73.119:8128
    [Title1] => (#1 - 266/1000) 181.FM - POWER 181 -=[: The Hitz Channel :]=- www.181.fm
    [Length1] => -1
    [File2] => http://108.61.73.118:8128
    [Title2] => (#2 - 318/1000) 181.FM - POWER 181 -=[: The Hitz Channel :]=- www.181.fm
    [Length2] => -1
    [File3] => http://108.61.73.117:8128
    [Title3] => (#3 - 401/1000) 181.FM - POWER 181 -=[: The Hitz Channel :]=- www.181.fm
    [Length3] => -1
    [File4] => http://198.27.79.224:9770
    [Title4] => (#4 - 27/50) 181.FM - POWER 181 -=[: The Hitz Channel :]=- www.181.fm
    [Length4] => -1
    [Version] => 2
)
```

The only thing you have to be careful of here is double-quotes in the original title values; you could use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) to fix this if you needed.