# insert parsed data into database table

Tags: php, arrays, parsing, insert, sqlsrv

I am new to php and trying to do the following:

**1) parse a PLS file from an external link** 
(which I've managed to do it using stack overflow example here: [How do I parse a .pls file using PHP? Having trouble with parse_ini_file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18174908/how-do-i-parse-a-pls-file-using-php-having-trouble-with-parse-ini-file))

**2) Insert the Title and File data obtained from parsed code into a database table like this:**

output format from parse code:

[Title1] => testradiostn

[File1] => http://testradiostn.com/

How do i put these two in an array so that I can insert it into a table like below

```
--------------------------------------------------
| id |   radio_stn    |      url                 |
-----|----------------|--------------------------|
| 1  |   testradiostn | http://testradiostn.com/ |
| 2  |  testradiostn2 | http://testradiostn2.com/|
| 3  |      x         |         x                |
| 4  |      x         |         x                |


$title = ???; //title from parsed pls file
$file = ???; //file from parsed plsm file

/*Also how do I insert more than one data at one go*/
$sql = "INSERT INTO Table_1 (radio_stn, url) VALUES (?, ?)";    
$params = array($title, $file);

$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql, $params);
```

Sorry for the long post.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like you inserting three values instead of two

Comment: Lol, I'm even more confused now on what you were asking....

Answer (score 0):

> How do i put these two in an array so that I can insert it into a table like below

To put `$title` and `$file` into an array, you would do like:

```
$params = array($title, $file);
```

Answer (score 0):

What parse_ini_file returns is an associative array. That means you should access elements by key name. To get a *file* and *title* you can var_dump the parsing result to see its structure . But probably something like this should work if I understood your question :

```
$title = $result['title']; 
$file = $result['file'];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yes that is exactly what I wanted to know. I tried the example you provided it just gives me nothing no errors, just blank page. I tried echo $title; echo $file; to test it.

Comment: I said "probably", because I don't know the structure of resulting array. Try to use var_dump(parse_ini_file(...your code here...)); to see what is returned.